# JNI C call Java function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I've been turning in circle for hours on this one... Im porting an old android app to 11 and try to open a URL from C. Previously I was opening URL using:

```
if( fork() == 0 )
{ execvp( "/system/bin/am", cmd ); }
```

But now it seems we cannot run commands using execvp directly anymore, so the idea is to call from C a Java function to open a browser and launch the URL. So now I got the following:

**[Utils.java]**

```
package com.android.MyApp;

public class Utils {

    public static void open_url(String url) {
        // Test it out...
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

**[main.c]**

```
void test( void ) {

    jclass cls = (*g_env)->FindClass( g_env, "com/android/MyApp/Utils" );

    jmethodID open_url = (*g_env)->GetStaticMethodID( g_env, cls, "open_url", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    (*g_env)->CallStaticVoidMethod( g_env, cls, open_url, (jstring)"https://stackoverflow.com/" );
}
```

Everything compile but Android Studio report on the CallStaticVoidMethod line: JVM object referenced by 'cls' is of type 'Class<MyApp.Utils>' and it does not have access to static method 'open_url(String)' declared in class 'Utils'.

And of course calling CallStaticVoidMethod even if g_env and cls got an address crash... How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `(jstring)"https://stackoverflow.com/"` <-- That's not how you create a `jstring`. You need to use `NewStringUTF` or `NewString`.

Comment: That was it NewStringUTF did the trick for me... Create an answer for it so I can accept it!